# SQL Error Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'date_format'

Tags: sql

This is straight out of the book and I keep getting this error not sure what it means or why I am getting since its the code written by the book Im supposed to be executing.

```
use forum;
SELECT m.subject,
date_FORMAT('m.date_entered,%M %D, %Y') AS Date
FROM users AS u 
INNER JOIN messages AS m
using (user_id)
WHERE u.username = 'funny man';
```

Comment: Hint:  `date_FORMAT('m.date_entered', '%M %D, %Y')`

Comment: That worked thank you!!